# How to Get my own Page after Login in joomla User Registration form

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using joomla User Registration form.

After successful login its showing user information page but I want to display my own page. How to change that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using login component you could set **Login Redirect Page** at:

```
Menus -> *Menu -> *Login Menu Item -> Options -> Login Redirect
```

If you are using login module you could set:

```
Extensions -> Module Manager -> *Login Module -> Login Redirection Page
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't get anything in menu and even module all so. i didn't installed any module i am using joomla inbuilt user registration form

Comment: Joomla registration form has to be connected to a menu item, you have to find it and make the setting in options tab.